# Best way to store temporary data from forms in Django?

Tags: django, django-views

I am currently designing a 3-step form to achieve orders in my website.
The client will start on step 1, fill some fields, then validate and go to step2 is the form is valid, and so on until the end.

As I'd like to do it without using Javascript, I'll create 3 Django views and 3 Django templates for each step.

The thing is I must wait until the end of step 3 before creating and saving objects in the DB. This means at the end of the step3, I should get information of the 3 steps before processing data.

The question is: what is the best way to store information from step 1 and 2 during the process (ex: session )?

Hope it's clear. Thanks for help.

Comment: I my point of view, yes. Session is the best solution. What other alternatives do you have? DB storage won;t be a good solution, it is useless for such temporary data. And if a user leaves your site, there is no sense to keep the data from steps 1/2 in memory

Comment: Thx! So to sum up, the "right" way is to perform data validation in each view, and if data is OK, do something like `request.session['name'] = name`then use all these session variables in the end of step3 ?

Comment: this is the approach I would take. At least session should have some benefits, right? It seems the legitmate to do so. But also have a look at the below answer regarding the form wizards.

Comment: @DavidW. That's exactly what form wizards do for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [form wizards](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/formtools/form-wizard/) - it is designed for exactly that. You can use either sessions or cookies to store data, both methods have a default `WizardView` that takes care of storing the data for you.

Comment: I didn't know about that. I just read it and you're right, it was exactly what I want to do :) Thanks for this.